# Increment ID in update of multiple rows in Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger that updates a students table record to a new ID on the column StudentsSID whenever an update is created. See the code below:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [Students_AfterInsertUpdate] ON [dbo].[Students]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @nID INT
    DECLARE @nIDCounter INT
    SET @nIDCounter = 0

    SET @nID = 10

    UPDATE Students
    SET ID = @nID
    WHERE SID IN
    (
        SELECT StudentSID FROM inserted UNION SELECT StudentSID FROM deleted
    )
   AND (ID IS NULL OR ID < @nID)

GO
```

The problem I'm having is that when multiple records are passed into the trigger at the same time, the ID does not get incremented - all the multiple records will have the same value for ID (in this case 10). Is there anyway that I can use the counter (@nIDCounter) and increment the value for @nID for each row? So that say if there's 3 records coming in, their ID's are 10, 11, 12 respectively. How is this possible?

Comment: Of course they get the same value. You have it hardcoded in your trigger. Why not just use an identity for this instead of wrestling with a trigger? You could also possibly look at using ROW_NUMBER but that seems like way more effort than it is worth.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why are you updating the ID field manually?  Does the program you're using use that ID to look for updated/new records or something?